# wordpress page flicker

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-ui-accordion

Any clues as to why the screen flickers each time a new page is loaded using wordpress. I have viewed in multiple browsers all with the same flickering effect.

It is especially noticeable when clicking on the side navigation.

I am using the jQuery accordion plugin with cookies enabled and "pretty" permalinks which may be a clue as to why the page is flickering. I also have a conditional to swap out the background image and a custom style sheet per section of the site. However, I have tried disabling each one of these settings one by one still with no luck. Thanks in advance if anyone is able to help.

http://hyload.go2mktg.com/roofing

Answer (score 0):

Take out your `fast.fonts.com` js reference.

Comment: This stops the screen from flashing but the jQuery accordion still appears to be very choppy.

Answer (score 0):

Each page has a new background images that needs to be downloaded and the styles re-applied.

Once you download all the background images, they should be cached and the flicker should disappear.

You can also take all your JQuery functions and put them in a DOM Ready file at the bottom of your page which will ensure they're only run after the page is completely loaded. Even though they're at the bottom it would be good practice and may help :}